# Find div tag and replace with span

Tags: reactjs

I have React component that renders some HTML with `<div>` tag. I want to use that component in `<p>`, but that occurs error `<div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>`.
Can I find that div and replace it with `<span>` tag?

What I need to find:
`<div hidden></div>`

Comment: Can't you change the `<div>` to a `<span>` in the first place?

Comment: That component from big library, I couldn't find that code ((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really replace an element type like that. Assuming you don't have direct access to this component, you could do some convoluted thing where you wrap the component in a div with a given ref, use that ref to select your element, save it's children, remove it, create a new element, etc, etc.

But you'll probably be much better off just not using a `<p>` tag in this instance, or figuring out if you have any ability to modify those elements through whatever package youre using.